# jquery extrack class of child and filter

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<div class="target">
<div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item wat ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
<div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item ura ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
        <div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item wat ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
<div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item ura ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
        <div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item ura ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
<div class="empty ui-droppable"><div class="item mox ui-draggable" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="closer"></span>
</div></div>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the an specific component of each item that lives within the target.

the component is within the first child of each item.

the component is the class wat, mox, or ura.

I have tried many methods but i can't get it to work. :/

if anyone can tell what to do next it would be greatly appreciated.

btw, if u get it to work it needs to be put in a array like:
[:ura,:wat,:plu,.......,:ura]

Thanks in advance

my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/LdeGC/2/

Comment: "I would like to extract the an specific component of each item that lives within the target." What specific component? Do you mean the HTML of the element, the class of its children elements, etc?

Comment: Show me what you have tried. Then I'll might fix it. Also, what "items lives in the target"? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you if you always keep the classes you are looking for in the second position as you have them in the fiddle i.e. : 'item CLASSYOUWANTTOEXTRACT'

http://jsfiddle.net/tsyhn/

All I do is go through each item, grab the class attr as a string, split it on the space, and take the 2nd element. Hope this works for you.

```
var itemArray = [];

$('.source .item').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), classes = $this.attr('class').split(' ');

    itemArray.push(':' + classes[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Im trying become a better programmer how do you think i should go about it next time?

Comment: one thing you should look into jquery data : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ . instead of having a class that holds that information, put it in a data attribute like data-item-type="ura" and you can access it in javascript like $('selector').data('item-type').

Comment: Why not save yourself the jQuery method call and simply use `classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);` and if you're only using `$(this)` once there's no point caching it really (caching is exactly as expensive as calling it uncached in this instance).